# Excel Concatenate column

Tags: excel

I am working with Excel and I need to concatenate product ID's with a comma next to them. Example column A has 1-1760 product ID's and I want to concatenate all the product ids with a comma (,). I would like to add these in one line in column B2 (=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).

[image]

Comment: There is no "easy" way of doing that (no formula). You need to create your own macro in vba to do that. Loop through cells and add into a string the value with a comma between them

Comment: Do you mean that you want one cell to have 1,760 numbers separated by commas?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestJoin()

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyArray() As Variant

Set MyRange = Range("A1:A5")
MyArray = Application.Transpose(MyRange)
Range("B1") = Join(MyArray, ",")

End Sub
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, is Transpose a handy way of getting a range into a 1d array?

Comment: @TomSharpe Yes, for a range in one column,  that's correct.

Comment: @TomSharpe Similarly, if you have a single row of values you would use the `Transpose()` function twice: `Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(MyRange))`.

Comment: Thanks very much - that's useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like the following:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim i As Long

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select
    i = 0
    Do
        ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value _
        + CStr(ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0)) + ","
        i = i + 1

    'change 21 to whatever number you want to reach (or use a variable/constant)
    Loop While i <= 21 - 2 
End Sub
```

However on the result you get from the above you have to remove the last added coma that the above function will put automatically. You can do that using the `left()` function of vba combined with `len()-1`